# Problems using Workbook.SaveCopyAs and Workbook.SaveAs with OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba

Using `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strFilePath` produces the error

> 'Run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined'

Using `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strFilePath` (same file path as above) works fine.

Note: `strFilePath` is a OneDrive file path like `"https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxxxxxxx/some folder/some other folder/filename.xlsm"`

Manually using `Save Copy` through the GUI technically works but the is no difference between using `Save Copy` through the GUI and using `SaveAs` via VBA (or the GUI). As far as I understand using `Save Copy` should create a new file but leave the current file open ([see here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-Copy-before-editing-to-prevent-changing-the-original-file-8aeabebe-952e-449b-b931-ae2b7568771b)). In my case the "new" file is open and the "old" one closed.

How can I get `Workbook.SaveCopyAs strFilePath` to work without returning an error and as it's suppose to (keep the old/original file open, and "leave" the new/copied file closed)?

Comment: You can only use SAveCopyAs on an open file.  If you need to make copy of a closed file there are other ways to do that.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, but this doesn't apply in my case, the file I'm trying to save is open (I added `ThisWorkbook` in my question to clarify).

Comment: Referencing this MSDN post, it looks like SaveCopyAs doesn't work with sharepoint, and therefore I'm assuming OneDrive as well. The post offers a workaround (I didn't try). Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e6a3a94-e528-451b-866d-2b552c4e53e8/xl-vba-savecopyas-into-sharepoint-not-working-but-save-as-is-fine?forum=exceldev

Comment: If you want the "old" (original) file to be closed, then why not use `Save` followed by `SaveAs` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams No, I want the old (original) file to be left open (that's how "Save Copy" is suppose to work).

Comment: @TechnoDabbler Thanks, I'm already using a similar workaround which works fine but it means that the file has to be saved 2 times which I want to avoid (the file is quite big and I'm using mobile internet access).

Answer (score 0):

coming here long time after the last post but... had the same problem in 2023 so ...
I found this workaround. You simply need to relocate the URI file to local computer.

Example : URI of a OneDrive localized file = "https://d.docs.live.net/b034d490c9cb9445/Documents/50 - Working"

You have to rebuild the local path by replacing "https://.../.../" with local path.
To do this you can get the OneDrive Path from the local environnement in vba with ENVIRON command => ENVIRON("OneDrive") return the local path of OneDrive

Example here. Adapt it as you need :)

```
Public Function fRelocateOneDrivePath(strParamURIPath As String) As String

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    
    ' Replace all "/" by "\" if exists
    strPath = Replace(strParamURIPath, "/", "\")
    
    If Left(strParamURIPath, 4) = "http" Then

        ' Remove the OneDrive URI part of the path : ex : "https://d.docs.live.net/b034d490c9cb9445/Documents/50 - Working"
        For I = 1 To 4
            strPath = Mid(strPath, InStr(strPath, "\") + 1)
        Next
        
        ' Return path with local OneDrivePath
        fRelocateOneDrivePath = Environ("OneDrive") & "\" & strPath
    
    Else
        ' Do Nothing
        fRelocateOneDrivePath = strParamURIPath
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: In your example you do not save the file at all, I'm not sure how this answers the question?!

Comment: Just use the function to rebuild the path.
ex :  ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fRelocateOneDrivePath(ThisWorkbook.Path) & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name